# rvest to properply check for html_text

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to harvest gender for a list of names using this function based on the following element `<a class="boy" href="/boys-names">Male</a>` for boys or `<a class="girl" href="/girls-names">Female</a>` for girls respectively.

```
library(rvest)    
gender_from_name <- function(name){
          name_url <- paste("https://nameberry.com/babyname/",  name, sep = "")
          is_it_a_boy <- read_html(name_url) %>% 
            html_nodes(".girl") %>% 
            html_text(trim=TRUE) %>% 
            length() == 0
          return (if(is_it_a_boy){"Male"}else{"Female"})
          }
```

However, it does not work for say `gender_from_name("Aaron")` . I tried with `length()<2` but it is still off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method to return the gender directly.  You are looking for the text under the "a" node under a "span" node under a "span" node with the class=meta-section.

```
library(rvest)    
gender_from_name <- function(name){
   name_url <- paste("https://nameberry.com/babyname/",  name, sep = "")
   is_it_a_boy <- read_html(name_url) 
   gender <- is_it_a_boy %>% 
      html_nodes("span.meta-section span a") %>% 
      html_text(trim=TRUE) 

   return (gender)
}

gender_from_name("Aaron")
gender_from_name("Mary")
gender_from_name("William")
gender_from_name("Dianne")
```

Comment: works for most, but not for for dual,  say [Barry](https://nameberry.com/babyname/Barry).  I guess it's the website deficiency as Barry is likelier to be a boy

Comment: @Vrun, Ok I adjusted the code slightly to check for both and now returns "Both".  Too bad there is no stats are reported to determine with which gender is the preference.